# Best way to code an HTML/CSS/JS tab navigation system (no images)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, tabs

I'm coding a tab system for my website that must be entirely CSS/HTML/JS (without using any images).  Problem is, I keep hacking the code until when I'm finished its just a mess.  I don't know whether to use positioning, or float the tabs or what.  Basically one of the big problems is that after I take away the bottom-border CSS of the selected tab, I need to move it down 1px so it seamlessly blends with the sorting headers - I don't know whether to use margin: -1px or position: relative/absolute etc.  I'd love some advice on a good way to code a tab system like this, so that it can be reused across the website!

[image]

Comment: Stay away from negative positioning/margins/padding at all costs.

Comment: @otis why oh why! I use negative margins all the time. Can be very handy.

Comment: I don't understand your "sorry they are so faded" comment; did you leave the image sitting out in the sun too long?

Comment: @thomasfedb Wow, after some research I guess they aren't as bad as I once thought. I just remember when learning css how everyone would say to avoid them. Turns out they are now more accepted. Go figure.

Comment: @lord, the original design we did was really really faded and hard to see - we revamped it so it was easier on the eye but I just put a little apology in case people were straining to see the outlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example with CSS that makes it work:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#item3">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabInner">
            <div id="item1">
                bla1
            </div>
            <div id="item2">
                bla2
            </div>
            <div id="item3">
                bla3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.tabs ul li {
    float: left;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.tabs ul li.active {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.tabInner {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
}

.tabInner div {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

It even works without JS (to some degree). You'll still need some JS to move the 'active' class arround and also if you want fancy transitions.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/V8CK4/

Comment: Thanks, worked really well!  I'll show you what I ended up with when I commit it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use divs nested inside a list.

```
<ul>
<li>Tab1
    <div> Content for Tab1</div>  
</li>
<li>Tab2
    <div> Content for Tab2</div>  
</li>
<li>Tab3
    <div> Content for Tab3</div>  
</li>
</ul>
```

Then with css style ul li div to not show. I would use jQuery to show the child divs upon click of the parent li.

EDIT: Thanks to the comment... Note the li's would have to be styled inline so they do not break line after every one. Also set the li list-style to none.

Comment: I like this solution, and I've used it myself.  But you should note that it requires `display: inline`.

Comment: Persoanlly I beleive that it can get a little messy getting the inside divs into position. Also this will probably degrade in non-JS browsers not quite as well as the solution I describe below.

Comment: Yeah thomas your solution degrades better.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I would write it like this:

```
<div class="tabContainer">
    <ul class="tabList">
        <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <em class="tabMessage">This is the message on the right.</em>

    <div class="tabInnerContainer">
        <div id="item1">
            bla
        </div>
        <div id="item2">
            bla
        </div>
        <div id="item3">
            bla
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way will allow you to make it function al least to some extent without Javascipt, degrading nicely in browsers with JS turned off. Some of the classes could be removed if using CSS3 sleectors.

Comment: I also recomend you use jQuery or similar if you can for the js.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how would you move the selected tab down so that it overlapped 1px with the bottom of the InnerContainer so they blended into looking like one piece?  Absolute positioning, negative margins?

Comment: I would give that li a negative -1px bottom margin, or a top margin of 1px. And I'd keep everything relative.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is to make the tab and the bar below it seem like one piece without using too much code.

What I have done before is to make the two elements I want to join overlap slightly (or not at all) and then put a third element (in the same color as both other elements) where the overlap is. This acts as a kind of *patch*.

Like this:

**I. without patch**

```
     _________________ 
    |                 |
    |    tab          |
  __|_________________|________________________________
 |                                                     |
 |       menu bar                                      |
 |_____________________________________________________|
```

**II. with patch**

```
     _________________ 
    |    tab          |
    |- - - - - - - - -|
 ___|    patch        |_______________________________
|    - - - - - - - - -                                |
|        menu bar                                     |
|_____________________________________________________|
```

You will only need to use `z-indexes` to make this work properly. The patch may extend over the tab div it is contained in by using `position: absolute` and an adequately high value for `top`.

**Update: demonstration**

http://jsfiddle.net/7GJaW/

Comment: This seems overly messy and non-semantic, if it can be achived without excess elements, why wouldn't you?

Comment: For one, your example does not cover rounded borders. My solution addresses this nicely. Also it is neither messy nor non-semantic (what does that mean anyway?). I posted a link to a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Like @Otis mentioned, nesting is a pretty good technique. I usually nest ul's

- Link 1
- - Link 1 Item 1
  - Link 1 Item 2

However, if you are not trying to attempt to do a dropdown...

Comment: Thats exactly what I use, except a div would work better in this example. Plus its easy to manipulate nested elements through javascript/jquery.